# Python Matplotlib generate graph from CSV

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I have a CSV file which contains two columns of data, the first column is time in the 24 hour format, i.e. 13h20m10s.

I am trying to pull this data out and plot it in a a graph using matplotlib. I have this line of code:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('graph.csv', dtype='str', delimiter =',', skip_header=0, usecols=[0], autostrip='true')

x = [mdates.date2num(dt.datetime.strptime(x[0], '%Hh:%Mm:%Ss')) for x in data]
print(x)
y = np.loadtxt('graph.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=0,usecols=[1])
print(y)
```

However when I run it I get the error

> "ValueError: time data '1' does no match format '%Hh:%Mm%Ss'

if I change the code for the x data to:

```
x = [mdates.date2num(dt.datetime.strptime(x[0], '%H')) for x in data]
```

the script will run, but my time values are then wrong... obviously.

Can anyone help with why it will not plot correctly?

Comment: The format string must match the data. If the data is `13h20m10s`, the format string must be `'%Hh%Mm%Ss'`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the : marks. You don't have those in the time column you describe

```
import datetime as dt
dateString='13h20m10s'
date_with_format = dt.datetime.strptime(dateString,'%Hh%Mm%Ss')
```

Comment: thanks - I have reformatted this and when I run the script the print(x) function is returning values which are for example -- 14h58m39s is converted to 693596.6240625 -- i'm not sure what is going on here?

Comment: Because 14h58m39s has not accompaniying date, it is assumed to be the 1900-01-01 14:58:39. Hence the number 693596.6240625 tells you that 1900-01-01 14:58:39 is (693596.6240625 - 1) days after the 0001-01-01 00:00.

Comment: That is days since 0001-01-01 00:00:00 and is the result of date2num,
 check more on that here (https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html). If you simply want the datetime, you can drop date2num which is what i have done in my example.

Comment: @en_lorithai Sorry I must be misunderstanding you - when I try your example it returns "1900-01-01 13:20:10" this is still including a date?! I only want the time, i'm not concerned about the date at all. Thanks

Comment: @CPS13 the datetime format includes year,month,date as well as clock data. If you don't specify the year,month and date it simply sets it to 1900-01-01. You can use the dt.time() instead.